# Integration involving exponential function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to find the following integral

$\int_t^s e^{-\frac{(\sqrt{x^2-a^2}-u)^2}{\sigma^2}    }  e^{-\frac{b^2}{x^2}}  dx$

where $t<u<s$, I can find a solution for $u=0$, but I need the solution for general case.

Comment: The $($non-trivial$)$ presence of $\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$ *begs* for a hyperbolic substitution of the form $x=a\cosh t$. However, given that the only $($special$)$ functions known to possess such an expression in their integral form are the **Bessel and Struve functions**, which unfortunately require fixed integration limits, it would appear that your (indefinite) integral is inexpressible even in terms of such special functions. And even if the two limits were $(0,\infty)$, I am still unsure if the integral is expressible even in terms of these special functions.